# JavaFX - How to get information which specific node in component are being focused?

Tags: user-interface, javafx

In my JavaFX app I want to by hitting "edit" button in Menu make focused Tree item edit property on, so user can overwrite new name of this item. I don't see any generic method except isFocused which only return information about whole component to let me know which item specificly are being focused in this moment. How can I make it happen?

Comment: [requestFocus()](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#requestFocus())

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#focusOwnerProperty

The Scene class has a focusOwner.